# how to integrate ViewPagerExtensions library android

Tags: android, layout

any example/reference would be greatly appreciated

library link https://github.com/astuetz/ViewPagerExtensions

Comment: Too short a question. What do you want to do with the integration?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [zip file](https://github.com/downloads/astuetz/ViewPagerExtensions/ViewPagerExtensions-Example_1.zip) containing the example code.  That link is found here : https://github.com/astuetz/ViewPagerExtensions

Comment: getting jar mismatch fix your dependencies ? sorry for asking silly questions but i am new to android